# Django YearArchiveView Year offest?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a simple calendar application that will track events across a School Year (Aug-May). What I would like to do is have an archive view that will allow the user to select a school year and see that school year’s worth of events.

For this I thought I would use the Django Class YearArchiveView. The issue is, I am not sure how to filter the results so that instead of getting a Jan to Dec result to get Aug to May.

View:

```
class EventArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    template_name = "cal/cal_archive.html"
    queryset = CalEvent.objects.all()
    date_field = 'start_date'
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True
```

Model:

```
class CalEvent(Audit):
    CAL_CHOICES = (
        ('HOLIDAY','Holiday'),
        ('SECONDARY','Secondary'),
        ('ELEMENTARY','Elementary'),
        ('TEACHER','Teacher'),
        ('TERM','Term'),
        ('TESTING','Testing'),
        ('GRAD','Graduation'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CAL_CHOICES,default='HOLIDAY')
    start_date = models.DateField(help_text="Format: M/D/Y")
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True,help_text="Format: M/D/Y. Not Required. Fill if event will spans multiple days.")
    week = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def cat_verbose(self):
        return dict(CalEvent.CAL_CHOICES)[self.category]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cal Events"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try overriding the dates using the following methods

```
class EventArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    template_name = "cal/cal_archive.html"
    queryset = CalEvent.objects.all()
    date_field = "start_date"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True

    def _get_current_year(self, date):
        return date.replace(month=8, day=1)

    def _get_next_year(self, date):
        return date.replace(year=date.year+1, month=5, day=1)
```

Comment: This works. But how do you oder the list to "-date"?